# How to use code to cancel DataGridView cell edit similar to the behavior when the user presses the Esc key?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to cancel a DataGridView cell edit when validating a wrong value similar to what happens when the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

My code like below but its behavior still different from pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
private void dgvSPS_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        dgv.CurrentCell.Value = string.Empty;
        e.Cancel = true;
        dgv.EndEdit()
        return;
    }
}
```

I want behavior when validating is wrong like pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

1. clear current cell
2. remove new line (if current cell is new line)
3. current cell focus to last row cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CancelEdit()`](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit) method:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    
    // Just an example for a "wrong value".
    bool someCondition = (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == "c");
    if (someCondition)
    {
        dgv.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Note that for requirement #3, this will only return the focus to the cell that was being edited if it's a new row. If that's not good enough and you want to focus the previous cell no matter what, you may add `e.Cancel = true;` and `dgv.EndEdit();` back in the `if` block:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    dgv.CancelEdit();   // Discards changes.
    e.Cancel = true;    // Forces the focus to remain in the current cell.
    dgv.EndEdit();      // Exit the editing control which is still active
                        // because of e.Cancel.
}
```